# jQuery load not loading content

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
$('a.uiAjaxModal').click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $modalHtml = '<div class="uiModalWrapper"><div class="uiModal"><!--content here--></div></div>';

            $($modalHtml).find('.uiModal').load($(this).attr('href'));

            $('body').append($modalHtml);

        });

<a class="uiAjaxModal" href="/Organisations/New">New</a>
```

It appends the modal fine but the content isn't loaded in and I get no errors in the Console!

**Also** how could I make it so that the modalHtml is ONLY appended to the dom on a click event like I have done in my code BUT make sure that only one instance of it can exist on the screen?

Comment: Tip: Are you checking on a local page with google chrome ? load() does now work on local pages with google chrome. This gave me hadaches until i found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `.ajax()` instead which works fine and has much better options

Answer (score 0):

make the string to a jquery object, because you are using a jquery object in the ajax, but what you append is a string, not a jquery reference:

```
$('a.uiAjaxModal').click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $modalHtml = $('<div class="uiModalWrapper"><div class="uiModal"><!--content here--></div></div>');

        $modalHtml.find('.uiModal').load($(this).attr('href'));

        $('body').append($modalHtml);

    });

<a class="uiAjaxModal" href="/Organisations/New">New</a>
```

and if you only want it to run once then look at [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I think the selector is invalid. please try this

$('.uiModalWrapper').find('.uiModal').load($(this).attr('href'));